# Row not created but increments primary key

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am attempting to insert new rows into the following PostgreSQL table:

```
                                       Table "public.users"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 user_id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('define_user_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 time_created  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 is_active     | boolean                  |           | not null | true
 email_address | text                     |           | not null |
 password_hash | character varying(255)   |           | not null |
 first_name    | text                     |           |          |
 second_name   | text                     |           |          |

Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_to_device" CONSTRAINT "user_to_device_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    TABLE "user_to_horse" CONSTRAINT "user_to_horse_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

The table currently only contains 10 records as it is still being used for development. There is no scope to modify the table.

My issue is that, when updating the table from a REST API the operation seemingly successfully and returns a new `user_id`; upon querying the table, the supposedly created user is not in the table.

If I then create a user manually (SSH'd into the server that's running psql) and use the exact same query then the operation is successful and the newly created user can be seen. Interestingly, the `user_id` value increments from the value created by the query triggered by the REST API.

This suggests to me that the query triggered via the REST API is successful (?) because the `user_id` that it creates seems to be recognised by subsequent queries - so why then does the new user not appear in the table?

No errors are thrown at all. Here's the query that I'm using to create a user:

```
INSERT INTO users (password_hash, is_active, first_name, email_address, second_name, time_created) VALUES ('mypasswordhash', True, 'Orson', 'user@example.com', 'Cart', '2018-11-23T12:23:00Z') RETURNING user_id;
```

I am using `psycopg2` from within Python 3.6 when querying via the API. I have multiple other API endpoints that INSERT successfully into other tables so I'm not sure at all what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated as this has me truly stumped, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a missing `commit` somewhere in your code

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It runs through the same function that is updating, inserting and deleting to and from other tables correctly. A `commit` is definitely called.

Comment: Generation of the primary key using a sequence happens before constraints are checked. If some constraint is violated the records will not be inserted but the sequence would be incremented. May it be the problem in your case?

Comment: @RomanKonoval I don't believe so but I will do some testing around this area. If this was the case, however, would psql not throw an error?

Comment: @RomanKonoval On second thoughts, this *can't* be the issue. The same query (using identical values) works when I `INSERT` locally.

Comment: Maybe there is a trigger which checks users permission or other conditions which are different between api and manual call.

Comment: I think the best approach to investigate this is to enable logging of all queries in the database (also make sure that transaction id is included in the log) and check what statements are executed in that transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you **absolutely** sure 
your `commit` function is called? 
In some cases 
if you `yield` or `return` 
before committing,
the function is aborted 
before your changes get committed.

In this case, I would expect to see 
an incremented ID without an inserted row, 
as primary keys get incremented 
before the query is checked. 
If your connection terminates abruptly,
the row won't get committed.

Your best bet would be to 
examine your PostgreSQL server logs.